# How do you model an array in YANG?

Tags: yang

### Summary

I want to create a YANG model for an ordered list of not-necessarily-unique numbers. For example, `[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 5, 17, 0, 0]`.

### Problem

A `list` [requires a key](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7950#section-7.8.2). My data does not have keys. I cannot use the values as keys because I want to allow repeats.

```
list items {
    key value; // cannot do this. Need to allow repeats
    leaf value {
        type uint8;
    }
    ordered-by user;
}
```

`leaf-list` values [must be unique](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7950#section-7.7). I need to allow repeats, so this won't work.

```
leaf-list items { // cannot do this. Need to allow repeats
    type uint8;
    ordered-by user;
}
```

### What I Want to Avoid

Is adding a separate unused leaf to a list really the only way?

```
list items {
    key annoying-useless-thing;   // DO NOT USE
    leaf annoying-useless-thing { // DO NOT USE
        type uint8;               // DO NOT USE
    }                             // DO NOT USE
    leaf value {
        type uint8;
    }
    ordered-by user;
}
```

Now all my xpaths change from `<my-path>/items` to `<my-path>/items/value` and I have some useless `annoying-useless-thing` nodes that I need to worry about keeping unique every time... I now have config data that isn't really part of the config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you stated, there is no array-like YANG statement where instance repetitions would be allowed, with the exception of keyless `config "false"` `lists` and `config "false"` `leaf-lists`, which won't help you model configuration.

You could model this as a single `leaf` of `type "string"` with a carefully crafted `pattern` restriction. That would complicate your XPath expressions a bit (you mention them in your question so I assume they are important), but with some YANG 1.1 `re-match()` XPath function dark magic it should be possible to impose further restrictions based on the `leaf's` value elsewhere - at least in part.

A quick example:

```
  leaf items {
    type string {
      pattern '\s?(0|[1-9][0-9]*)(\s?,\s?(0|[1-9][0-9]*))*\s?';
    }
  }
```

And if you don't need to leverage built in YANG value validation, there's always the good old normative text in YANG `descriptions`, where you can describe the intention behind the value in detail. That won't help non-humans though.

Comment: Thank you, that is an interesting approach. I wonder how the performance of "get" operations would be. For example, extracting the element at index `i` would require retrieving the whole leaf and parsing it. However it is a tradeoff worth exploring since it would mean I can skip some other validation elements in my model.